# Twilio channel getMembers method doesn't return all members

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm writing a chat powered by twilio API. I have a problem with creating a channel and then obtaining all of its members.

The flow is following:

- Frontend hits an endpoint on the backend which is responsible for creating a channel
- Backend creates a channel
- On the Frontend I receive event `channelAdded` (this is from twilio sdk)
- In the event callback I receive a channel as an argument
- I call `.getMembers()` method on this newly created channel

And... the problem is that this method returns wrong number of members. I created a channel with 5 members, but the method returned only 3 of them. After I refresh the page everything works as expected - `.getMembers()` returns 5 members. It looks like there might be some race conditions somewhere. I could "wait" on every new channel a second or two - it feels very hacky, but probably solves this issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're likely right in that this is a race condition. I would approach this by adding a `memberJoined` listener to the channel as soon as you receive the `channelAdded` event. That way you can load the existing members with `.getMembers()` and catch any still being added with the event listener.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Just a bit off topic but what ought one to do if author member gets 54007 on Channel.getMembers()? When I add the members, I run Channel.add(identity) for both the author and other user.

Comment: Hey @KasparTr, the comments aren’t a great place for off topic questions. There’s not enough space to get the details. I’d recommend asking a new question with as much detail as possible.

Comment: you are totally right. Added new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61728239/twilio-chat-channel-getmembers-method-access-forbitten